# Changing String encoding type to send in HTTP Request

Tags: java, urlencode

I have a `String` that contains for example:

```
Hello are you ok ?
```

I want to convert this String to:

```
Hello%20are%20you%20ok%20?
```

What do we call that and how can I do it in Java? Cause when I send a `HttpRequest`, the server doesn't understand the words without these special characters...

Comment: You only want to encode the spaces?

Comment: It's called URL encoding: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10786042/java-url-encoding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want to use is [URLEncoder](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/net/URLEncoder.html) :

String encodedUrl = URLEncoder.encode(url, "UTF-8");

Comment: If `url` is `http://www.google.com/`, the encoded form is `http%3A%2F%2Fwww.google.com%2F` (a mess).  The duplicate Q&A answers this much better.